# Склоняется ли Ураза-байрам?

Tags: грамматика

С названием этого сегодняшнего мусульманского праздника какая-то недоговоренность. Прежде всего, зачем прописная (которой, кстати не было в  словарях более старых), если это не имя собственное?

Но это ладно, можно как-то объяснить. А вот кк насчет склонения первой части? Празднуют Уразу-байрам или Ураза-байрам? Если по аналогии с Курбан-байрамом, то верно второе, склонять первую часть не надо. Но Курбан-байрам никто и не склоняет по обеим частям. А вот *Уразу-байрам* так и хочется просклонять. Почему? И насколько правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ураза-байрам… Когда склоняется, то склоняется ли первая часть…  **И
>   лучше всего - на основании словаря**.

В словарях, представленных на Грамоте.ру, склоняется только вторая часть *Ураза-байрам**а***. [См.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D3%F0%E0%E7%E0-%E1%E0%E9%F0%E0%EC&all=x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Секундочку, а почему в "словарях"? Вижу один вариант в СИС. А у Лопатина, если что и вижу, то "-а", которое можно понять совершенно по-разному.

Comment: Хотя может быть... понял, он полностью пишет, когда обе части склоняются. Ладно, убедили. Понять бы еще, почему...

Answer (score 0):

"празднуют Ураза-Байрам" - 460 000 ссылок

"празднуют Уразу-Байрам" - 1650 ссылок

Это само по себе не доказательство, но показывает общеупотребительный тренд. Ну, а хочется просклонять, просто потому что русский родной и мозг склоняет на автомате. Англичанину не хочется. :)

Еще примеры склонения или не склонения термина.

"на Ураза-Байрам" - 37 800 ссылок

"на Уразе-Байраме" - 5 ссылок

Кстати, хочу отдельно поблагодарить юзера Begemothus за очень ценный, актуальный и волнующий многих носителей русского языка вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо.. Частотность в интернете меня не интересует.

Comment: Практический опыт показывает, что когда частотность между двумя вариантами отличается в сотни и тысячи раз, это по крайней мере повод задуматься. Особенно показательна разница в 5 и почти 40 тысяч ссылок.

Comment: А нормы и не устанавливаются. Интернет - это инструмент исследования (один из), дающий полезные и интересные намеки о фактическом словоупотреблении. Дальше уже не так сложно взять конкретные правила о том, когда имена собственные из других языков склоняются, когда нет. Элементарное рассуждение. Считайте на ход вперед-то, это не сложно.

Comment: Вот поэтому я и говорю, что частотность меня не интересует.

Comment: А стоило бы поинтересоваться. По крайней мере это лучше, чем заниматься абстрактной болтовней. Вам одиноко, верно? :)

Answer (score 0):

Грамота.ру рекомендует два варианта: склоняемый (вторая часть): Ураза-байрама и несклоняемый: в честь праздника Ураза-байрам.

Comment: Серж, спасибо, конечно,  я не сомневаюсь, что без родового слова название  склоняется, а с ним - нет. Это общее правило, я его знаю. Вопрос в другом. Когда склоняется, то склоняется ли первая часть. Уразы-байрама или Ураразы-байрама, Уразе-байраму или Ураза-Байраму - и т.д. И лучше всего - на основании словаря, а не ответов Справки, которае очень часто по-разному отвечает на одинн и тот же аопрос.